# Cartesian product with conditions

Tags: python, numpy

The below code works well to generate all the ways you can combine numbers that would sum to a certain value at a step size of 2.

Increasing the `to_val` and `axislengh` takes a significant toll on the execution.

Is there a way to improve the efficiency of the below?
If so, could you please share an example?

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

def yielder(ctproduct):
    for element in ctproduct:
        #Making sure the sum of the numbers is between from_val and to_val.
        if to_val>sum(element)>=from_val:
            yield element
    

axislengh= 4
from_val= 100 
to_val= 104
step=2

#Maybe this is not the best way.
args =[[i for i in range(0, to_val, step)] for x in range(axislengh)]
ctproduct= itertools.product(*args)  


df=pd.DataFrame(yielder(ctproduct))

df
```

Comment: maybe take a look at numpy and it's `arange` function. Also you can replace your yielder with a numpy.where

Comment: I feel like there may be a recursive/DP solution for this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code probabally acts slow because of al the for loops that you're using. you can make the code significantly faster by eliminating these loops, through vectorization or repeated references to the same object.

```
args = axislength * (range(0, to_val, step),)

ctproduct = np.array(list(itertools.product(*args)))
s = ctproduct.sum(axis= 1)

mask = (from_val <= s) & (s < to_val)

df = pd.DataFame(ctproduct[mask])
```